# Common workflows for SoA/ microservice architectures?

Tags: architecture, soa

What's the cleanest approach for a development environment if you were implementing a service oriented architecture?

How would you manage launching service X when you want to develop service Y?

There seems to be a lot of talk about the theoretical aspects of SoA, but how would this work in the real world when building out a multi-service app in Rails/Express/Etc?

Wouldn't it be hard to manage an application with numerous external services as dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wouldn't it be hard to manage an application with numerous external
>   services as dependencies?

It depends what you mean by *manage*. To my mind this means coordinating all the activities associated with delivering new functionality for a service into production, including planning, development, build, deployment, and operational support.

Management of a physically separated service with no binary dependencies with other services and no enforced referential integrity at the storage level with other services is *relatively* simple, and becomes and exercise in dependency management with the other services. Because these dependencies generally manifest as API contracts, contract versioning becomes a large consideration for system-level development and intra-team workflow. (Many strategies exist for this - as does a whole massive discussion on it's own).

However, I would put to you that you need to consider the difficulty of management when faced with the alternative. Well, what is the alternative to this approach? The alternative is the *monolith* application approach, and so you see why I highlighted the word "relative" in the previous paragraph.

I would urge you to read (or re-read) the opening paragraphs of James Lewis & Martin Fowler's microservices article [here](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html), where they do a much better job than I of explaining this.